# lateinit property value assigned but i face kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have assigned value for a lateinit variable in Kotlin when creating instance for fragment, Then i used the variable in fragment's oncreateview method. It works perfectly, but sometime it return kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException and my application was closed. I don't know when it occurred, i have checked multiple scenarios. but it never works.

Here i added my code,

```
private lateinit var mViewModel: SearchViewModel
companion object {
      fun getInstance(activity: Activity?): SearchFragment {
            val fragment = SearchFragment()
            fragment.mViewModel = SearchViewModel(activity)
            return fragment
      }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.search_fragment, container, false)
        mBinding.viewModel = mViewModel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Fragment.onCreateView` is called by the framework on an instance it creates by using the default constructor, not by calling your `getInstance` method which it doesn't know about.

Maybe you should initialize the variable in [`onAttach`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context)) instead?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this issue occurred due to device config changes, i have moved the viewmodel instance in oncreateview. Now its works well...